# Show loading while getting RSS feed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iframe, razor, rss

I am reading an RSS feed that takes a few seconds. What would be the best way to show a loading gif or something on the page while it is being retrieved, and hide it once it loads? This is actually in an iframe so space is limited, FYI. Suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
List<TwilioStatusMessage> tsmList = new List<TwilioStatusMessage>();
TwilioStatusMessage tsm = new TwilioStatusMessage();
string url = "http://status.twilio.com/rss?services=incoming-sms";

try
{
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();

    tsm.pubDate = feed.Items.First().PublishDate.ToString();
    tsm.description = feed.Items.First().Summary.Text;
    //tsm.link = url;
    tsmList.Add(tsm);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    tsm.pubDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    tsm.description = ex.Message.ToString();
    //tsm.link = url;
    tsmList.Add(tsm);
}

            @if (tsmList != null)
            {
                foreach (var itm in tsmList)
                {
                    @(itm.description) <em>@(itm.pubDate)</em>
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably not to load the feed 'synchrounously', but to fetch it and store it asynchrounsly and then show the results from your store/cache when you need them. This way you won't depend on the RSS feed to be up to show anything to your users.